# What is preselection?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, definition

Looking for a definition of preselection I find either statistical or electoral definitions. I was trying to find something similar to [What is postselection?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14269/what-is-postselection) or [What is postselection in quantum computers?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-is-postselection-in-quantum-computing) but for preselection in physics. Does it just mean to prepare a state?

Here is an example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.7482

It seems to be used in the context of weak measurements, see also https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.2721

Another one: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.50.2908

After reading for a while it seems to imply initial state in the weak measurement community. Why is this terminology used? maybe it has some relation to the [two-vector state formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-state_vector_formalism) of Aharonov. However a confirmation from somebody that understand this terminology would be great.

Comment: Can you link to some literature which uses this phrase in context?

Comment: @rob here is one

Comment: The example usage of "preselection" in the cited paper is somewhat unorthodox, as is their usage of "postselection".  Not saying it is wrong, just commenting that this particular paper is touching on a very complex subject (the validity of the Two State Vector Formalism vs. standard QM). When I see "postselection", I usually see it in context of coincidence counting in entanglement experiments - often when there are Bell State Measurements (which require postselection). Preselection is not often used as a term - again, not saying there is anything wrong with it in terms of the paper.

Comment: In the 2nd paper, figure 1, they prepare a beam of light ... seems to me to be the "pre-selection", the photons are in a known state. In the "post-selection" they likely use a polarizer to only look at certain photons  ... s or p reflections.  For the first paper I would assume pre just refers to the incoming beam and  post would refer to whatever is detected at the detectors in either arm.

Comment: @PhysicsDave I am under the impression that preselection just means initial preparation, in order to contrast with whatever is postselected.

Comment: yes .... I would agree.  Your question made me read up in wikipedia on the 2 state vector formalism referred to in the first paper ... and I ended up on the Wheeler Feynman theory ... all interesting ...

Comment: @Mauricio Preparation is a physical process. Post-selection is not. If you want to stay consistent, then one should not identify pre-selection just with physical processes. Just my two cents.

Comment: @FlatterMann I kind of get that but I am not the one using the terminology, these authors are.

Comment: Like I said, I am not sure that authors are using these terms in a consistent way. I am personally comfortable with the definition of post-selection in the way it is being used for statistical ensembles. The irreversibility of statistics makes it, for all I can see, meaningless to use the term pre-selection there. The reversibility of quantum mechanics does not have that restriction. The bigger problem, IMHO, is that post-selection and pre-selection are being use by various authors to make ontological statements about quantum systems that are neither supported by theory or observation.

Comment: @FlatterMann I understand that you do not like it, but the question can be reformulated to "is it implying anything else than initial state?". If not, what does it mean? If yes, I agree it might be a "misuse" of the term, but it is just a convention.

Comment: Yes, it does imply that. Post-selections do not have to be physical, i.e. they can be made in such ways that they could not be reproduced by an actual physical setup. They only exist in our minds and on paper (or computer memory). There is nothing wrong with that. Neither would there be anything wrong with making non-physical pre-selections. In both cases we are analyzing quantum mechanical ensembles that do not exist in nature. Whether that gives us any new information is probably situation dependent.

Comment: @PhysicsDave thanks for that! I think TVSF is a good clue of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to leave this as a comment, but it's too long.

No offense to the authors of the first paper, but they are performing an exercise in futility. "The photon" has never been anywhere other than where it has been detected. Standard QM does not make predictions about paths of quanta. It merely tells us the probabilities of detecting one as a function of the boundary conditions of the free field. As they notice in the end, other attempts to make such predictions lead to inconsistencies. Standard QM is "complete" in its description of observations, it's jut not very "satisfying" since it seems to tell us so little about the "internals" of quantum mechanical black boxes.

With regards to preselection... a rational definition IMHO would be to use it the same way as post-selection but for the reverse time problem. While this is not well defined in probability theory, it is well defined in quantum mechanics for all I know (disclaimer: I am not a theorist, so I might be overlooking a small detail that does not occur in practical applications which, of course, are always running in the same direction in time). I do not know if the literature uses if that way (or any other way) consistently. I suspect that it does not, but if we were to define a rational pair of opposites, then this seems like a rational choice.

Apologies for leaving an opinion piece in an answer.